# Is the Road Building Development card applicable for ships in Catan Seafarers?

Tags: catan, catan-seafarers

In the Seafarer's Expansion for Settlers of Catan, is the Road Building Development card applicable for ships?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the Road Building Development Card can be used for ships or roads.

From the [Seafarers rules](http://www.catan.com/service/game-rules), page 5.

> When playing the “Road Building” Development Card in a game of Seafarers, you have the option of building 2 roads, 2 ships, or
>   1 ship and 1 road.

Answer (score 0):

The "Road Building" progress card in Cities & Knights explicitly states that, when playing with Seafarers, you can play either 2 roads, 2 ships, or 1 of each.